# How do I implement tabs in an article that flush and load content when clicked on?

Tags: joomla-2.5

To be more specific, I have 2 video players loaded into an article on two different tabs. One is live, the other is on-demand. They don't play nice together, but it's nice to have them available on tabs instead of in two different articles completely.

I am looking for a tab plugin or even just tab code I can use in the article that will load and unload the tab contents so that when you're on tab 1, tab 2's contents aren't loaded at all, and when you click on tab 2, tab 1 is flushed and then tab 2's contents load.

is this even possible, or should I just use 2 different articles and a menu so that each player is on a different page?

Comment: What video player(s) are you using? I think this might be easier to solve by looking at them rather than the tabs.

Comment: Is that literally two different video _players_? And what do you mean by "don't play nice together"? WWIII?!

Comment: One of them is Make.tv, that's the live player. The other is Limelight, that's our on-demand player. Two completely different systems. When they're both on the same page, the live player loses functionality on a mobile device completely. And if we use the playlist function on the limelight player, it also breaks that function. The Make.tv player has no API, we literally can't do a thing with it except just paste the iframe code in. The limelight player does have an API so we have it working with a different type of playlist. But Make.tv still breaks on mobile.

Comment: Mobile safari has limited to no support for iframes.

Comment: The iframes work fine (content is loaded) they just conflict for some reason.

Comment: You could simply use jquery ui tabs in your template and use some javascript to unload/empty the other tab when teh user switches tabs? You need to find some way to load the video code from raw articles I suppose.

Comment: It's that jquery I was hoping someone would point me toward. We gave up on this for now. If Make.tv would get serious about their player it wouldn't be a problem.

Answer (score 1):

If both tabs contain iframes, you could use `$('#iframe').attr('src', 'http://example.com');` to set the iframe content (and `$('#iframe').attr('src', '');` to empty it. I made a small [jsfiddle (without the tabs)](http://jsfiddle.net/D9pv8/). I'm sure this code can be improved, and it has to be changed to fit your needs, but maybe it'll give you a push in the right direction:

**jQuery code**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    jQuery('.tab1').on('click', function (e) {
        $('#iframe2').attr('src', '');
        $('#iframe1').attr('src', 'http://example.com');
        e.preventDefault();
    });
    jQuery('.tab2').on('click', function (e) {
        $('#iframe1').attr('src', '');
        $('#iframe2').attr('src', 'http://example.com');
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

**HTML**

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#tab1" class="tab1">Tab #1</a> </li>
    <li><a href="#tab2" class="tab2">Tab #2</a> </li>
</ul>
<h2>iframe 1:</h2>
<iframe id="iframe1" frameborder="0" src=""></iframe>
<h2>iframe 2:</h2>
<iframe id="iframe2" frameborder="0" src=""></iframe>
```

Comment: I actually don't work at this employer any longer, but I may dig up the code for the two players and try this out anyway. Thanks!

Comment: OK, I see... Old post :) If you do test the code, please let me know if it worked, just out of curiosity.

Comment: I'm just trying to add an answer to some of the unanswered questions